# How to resolve error[The HTTP verb POST used to access path is not allowed] while implementing Speller page in .net application

Tags: php, asp.net, spell-checking

I have implemented Spell checker functionality in my .NET application as per given link below:

[**Speller page**](http://spellerpages.sourceforge.net/)

I copied the speller page in my application but i am getting error:

> The HTTP verb POST used to access path
>   '/WebAppUI/speller/speller/server-scripts/spellchecker.php' is not
>   allowed

Does anyone know how to resolve it.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you said that it is an asp.net application.  Does your server have PHP installed and IIS configured properly to process php pages?

Comment: I don't have PHP installed on my system and IIS not configured for php pages.Can u please guide me how to do it.Does this resolve my problem?

Comment: Yes that is your problem.  You are trying to use a php based server side solution in IIS.  You could install PHP: 

http://www.iis-aid.com/articles/how_to_guides/installing_php_5_iis_5_simple_steps

Or you could try to look for an IIS asp.net based solution.  Unfortunately, most asp.net based solutions are not free.

Comment: I have installed php.in 4th step they r asking for copy the php.ini-recommended file but i didn't find it so i copy php.ini-development file from PHP folder made changes as per need.In last step when i was testing it by adding new php file in my application it display simple text in browser.plz see image posted in my question.