# The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/rpc.php' is not allowed

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, tinymce, spell-checking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to resolve error[The HTTP verb POST used to access path is not allowed] while implementing Speller page in .net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274121/how-to-resolve-errorthe-http-verb-post-used-to-access-path-is-not-allowed-whil)

Am using Tiny MCE for Editing a content text in ASP.NET MVC4.

I want to use spell checker. For this i have to specify a php file. when i point path of that fie  in my local host it returns an error that  **"The HTTP verb POST used to access path '/rpc.php' is not allowed"** .

Should i specify any rights to access php file from asp.net mvc.

Is there any other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: have you installed php on your IIS server and configure it properly to work with IIS, if so can you access php file on your browser